# Add a column to an existing multirow element

Tags: tables, multirow

I have the following code:

Main.tex:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{techdoc}
\title{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text}
\subtitle{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text}
\department{R\&D}
\filepath{//path/to/file}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

techdoc.sty:

```
\ProvidesPackage{techdoc}

\RequirePackage[a4paper, hmargin=2.5cm, vmargin=1cm, includeheadfoot, headheight=3cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{array}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{xspace}
\RequirePackage{lastpage}
\RequirePackage[bookmarks, bookmarksopen,pdfstartview={FitH},colorlinks,linkcolor={black},citecolor={black}, urlcolor={black}]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{nameref}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{multirow}
\RequirePackage{wrapfig}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{tabu}
\RequirePackage{tocvsec2}
\RequirePackage{colortbl}
\RequirePackage[absolute]{textpos}
\RequirePackage{rotating}
\RequirePackage{url}
\RequirePackage[small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{makecell}

% fix some bug
\renewcommand{\nobreakspace}{\nobreak\ }

% make foot notes looks nice
\RequirePackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{7pt}

% Document information commands
\newcommand{\@confidentialitynotice}{Internal and Confidential Document}
\newcommand{\confidentialitynotice}[1]{\renewcommand{\@confidentialitynotice}{#1}}
\newcommand{\@subtitle}{}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{\renewcommand{\@subtitle}{#1}}
\newcommand{\@department}{}
\newcommand{\department}[1]{\renewcommand{\@department}{#1}}
\newcommand{\@filepath}{}
\newcommand{\filepath}[1]{\renewcommand{\@filepath}{#1}}
\newcommand{\@version}{}


% Tables
\definecolor{arrayrule}{rgb}{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\arrayrulecolor{arrayrule}
\newenvironment{nicetable}{\begin{table}[h!t]\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}\addtolength{\belowcaptionskip}{4pt}}{\end{table}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}

% Title page
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
    \newgeometry{headheight=0pt, headsep=0pt, hmargin=2.5cm, vmargin=2cm}
    \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\columnwidth-6cm-4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}|}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=2.7cm, height=2.0cm]{icon_caution}} & {\bf \@confidentialitynotice } & {\includegraphics[width=2.7cm, height=2.7cm]{icon_goal}} \\[0.3cm] \cline{2-2}
        & \multirow{2}{*}{\bf  \@title}\\[.6cm] \cline{1-1}
        \@department & \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}


    \vfill

    \begin{center}

    {\Huge \bf \@title}

    \rule{\columnwidth}{2pt}
    \vspace{0.1cm}

    {\LARGE \@subtitle}
    \end{center}

    \vspace{3cm}
    \vfill

    \end{titlepage}
    \setcounter{page}{2} % titlepage messes with my page counter!
    \restoregeometry
}
```

Which results in the following:
[image: Existing table]

I would like to delete the last row, and instead create a new column on the right with only one case that would be the symmetric of the icon plus R&D.

I have tried the following:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\columnwidth-6cm-4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=2.7cm, height=2.0cm]{icon_caution}} & {\bf \@confidentialitynotice } & {\includegraphics[width=2.7cm, height=2.7cm]{icon_goal}} \\[0.3cm] \cline{2-2}
    & \multirow{2}{*}{\bf  \@title}\\[.6cm] \cline{1-1}
    \@department & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

Which results in this:

[image: Current table]

How can I improve it to make it look good?

Edit: The icons, as asked in the comments:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can we get the icons?

Comment: @Bernard They are just placeholders, but I have added them.

Comment: What's your document class? Some two column class like ieee?

Comment: article, I edited the code to add everything in the title page section.

Comment: Your code, even completed with some obviously necessary packages produces no output whatsoever. Could you post a minimal, fully compilable code, staring with `\document class` and ending with `\end{document}`?

Comment: Sorry, there was a lot of cruft to remove, and still quite a lot, but here is a MWE.

Comment: There is something strange about your MWE. I do not have the time to figure it out atm, but the margins seem wrong. `\columnwidth` in tabular should probably be replaced but `\textwidth`, although the result will in this case be the same. However, here, the margins are wrong, so everything overlaps into the margin. When trying out new page-formats the `show frame` package is useful, and the `layout`-package. `Showframe` just needs to be loaded, but `layout` in addition need to be called with `\layout`. Also, I cannot see that you are using tabularx-functionality. Zarko's  answer reflects this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

[image]

For above picture I make own MWE, since I'm lost in yours. I believe, that you will easily adopt it to your needs:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[margin=25mm,showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{multirow,tabularx}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    \begin{document}

{    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\noindent%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|P{3cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash\bfseries}X|P{3cm}|}
    \hline
\multirow{3}*[2pt]{%
    \includegraphics[width=2.7cm,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}\smallskip~
    &   \rule[-3mm]{0pt}{9mm}
        Internal and Confidential Document\@confidentialitynotice 
        &   \multirow{2}*[2pt]{%
            \includegraphics[width=2.7cm,height=2cm]{example-image-b}}  
                        \\  \cline{2-2}
    &                                       
        &               \\
    &   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text%\@title     
        &               \\  \cline{1-1}
R\&D        &       &   \\  \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here another solution, with a simpler code. I simplified a bit your package, removing packages which are alreay called by other packages, such as `colortbl` which is called by the `table`  option of `xcolor`. Also, it is better to load `hyperref` after all other packages (there are some exceptions such as `cleveref`).

```
\ProvidesPackage{techdoc}

\RequirePackage[a4paper, hmargin=2.5cm, vmargin=1cm, includeheadfoot, headheight=3cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
%\RequirePackage{array}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{xspace}
\RequirePackage{lastpage}
\RequirePackage{nameref}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{multirow}
\RequirePackage{wrapfig}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{tabu}
\RequirePackage{tocvsec2}
%\RequirePackage{colortbl}
\RequirePackage[absolute]{textpos}
\RequirePackage{rotating}
\RequirePackage{url}
\RequirePackage[small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{makecell}
\RequirePackage[bookmarks, bookmarksopen,pdfstartview={FitH},colorlinks,linkcolor={black},citecolor={black},
urlcolor={black}]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{6pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{6pt}
% fix some bug
\renewcommand{\nobreakspace}{\nobreak\ }

% make foot notes looks nice
\RequirePackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{7pt}

% Document information commands
\newcommand{\@confidentialitynotice}{Internal and Confidential Document}
\newcommand{\confidentialitynotice}[1]{\renewcommand{\@confidentialitynotice}{#1}}
\newcommand{\@subtitle}{}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{\renewcommand{\@subtitle}{#1}}
\newcommand{\@department}{}
\newcommand{\department}[1]{\renewcommand{\@department}{#1}}
\newcommand{\@filepath}{}
\newcommand{\filepath}[1]{\renewcommand{\@filepath}{#1}}
\newcommand{\@version}{}


% Tables
\definecolor{arrayrule}{rgb}{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\arrayrulecolor{arrayrule}
\newenvironment{nicetable}{\begin{table}[h!t]\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}\addtolength{\belowcaptionskip}{4pt}}{\end{table}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}

% Title page
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
    \newgeometry{headheight=0pt, headsep=0pt, hmargin=2.5cm, vmargin=2cm}
    \sffamily
    \begin{titlepage}
       \centering\large
     \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}Sc|@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}X%
 @{}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}Sc|}
        \hline
       \raisebox{-0.6\height}{\includegraphics[width=2.7cm]{icon_caution}} &% \multirow{2}{*}{%
       \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering\bfseries\@confidentialitynotice\\[0.6cm]
       \hrule\vskip0.5cm\Large\@title}%}
        & \raisebox{-0.6\height}{\includegraphics[width=2.7cm]{icon_goal}}  \\
        \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
       \textit{\bfseries \@department}  &  &  \\
       \hline
    \end{tabularx}


    \vfill

    \begin{center}

    {\Huge \bfseries \@title}

    \rule{\columnwidth}{2pt}
    \vspace{0.1cm}

    {\LARGE \@subtitle}
    \end{center}

    \vspace{3cm}
    \vfill

    \end{titlepage}
    \setcounter{page}{2} % titlepage messes with my page counter!
    \restoregeometry
}
```

The main file: I loaded `lmodern`, instead of the default `cm`, in order to have italic boldface sans fonts.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{techdoc}
\title{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text}
\subtitle{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text}
\department{R\,\&\,D}
\filepath{//path/to/file}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, I ended up using yours since it was easier to understand. Just as a note, there's an added } after hyperref and it was complaining about the S option in the column specification; I removed the S and it seems to work.

Comment: @Leherenn: Thanks for pointing the typo (I found another one on checking). For the `S`,it's a pre-qualifier, added in front of `c`, `l`,`r`, &c.. Its aim is to give some vertical padding to a cell if necessary. It is defined  by the  `cellspace` package, and  should be replaced by `C` if you also load  `siunitx` (which defines a `S`column type).  Does it complain with this very code, or inserted in another file?

Comment: With this very code.

Comment: @Leherenn: I had loaded a old version of the modified `techdoc.sty`, without `cellspace`.Sorry for that error. Please see if it compiles with the updated version.

Comment: Compiles fine thanks, I had already made the change based on your previous comment. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to help!